# why I do not get the renamed column in R with title defined?

Tags: r, title

I am trying to created a function that parameters defined into the local environment that I hope to use it in a tibble.

here it is a reproducible example without yet creating the function:

```
tibble <- structure(list(standardised_existing_cond_rate = 1.44), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I am defining my title, an example which does not seem to be an issue when I add them together using paste function :

```
comorbidity <- "asthma"
title <- "Standardised"

add_to_title <- comorbidity
add_last_word <- " rate in"
country = "India"
country = country

whole_title <- paste(title, add_to_title, add_last_word, country)

whole_title
```

But then, when I rename my column name with the whole title I do not succeed.

```
table <- tibble %>% rename(whole_title = standardised_existing_cond_rate)

table
```

Clearly, I am trying to do something odd. yet, I wish I would find another more elegant solution as to how to get my column name renamed with the title. But important is to keep the whole title name as it is because these will be passed in as functions with the parameters defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!!` with `:=` to evaluate `whole_title` :

```
library(dplyr)
tibble %>% rename(!!whole_title := standardised_existing_cond_rate)

#  `Standardised asthma  rate in India`
#                                 <dbl>
#1                                 1.44
```

Also there are simpler ways without getting into non-standard evaluation. For eg with `setNames`

```
setNames(tibble, whole_title)
```

Comment: To evaluate the value of `whole_title` and not the literal work `whole_title` we use `!!` along with `:=` in `mutate`/`rename`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble %>% 
     rename_at(vars(standardised_existing_cond_rate), ~ whole_title)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  `Standardised asthma  rate in India`
#                                 <dbl>
#1                                 1.44
```

---

Or using `rename_with`

```
tibble %>% 
          rename_with(~ whole_title, standardised_existing_cond_rate)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  `Standardised asthma  rate in India`
#                                 <dbl>
#1                                 1.44
```

Comment: rename_with and ~ looks really nice!